# how to get data from listview if check any of the 3 checkboxes how to get the value of checked box and text from row

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

how to know which checkbox is checked and how retrieve data of each row and save it into a file

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<Inforowdata> rowdata;
    ArrayList<Inforowdatab> rowdatab;
    ArrayList<Inforowdatac> rowdatac;
    ListView l;
    //String[] data={"Ram", "Shyam", "Deepak", "sabdhs", "dsbndj", "dshg", "dsnd", "dsavg", "dbash", "dbshd", "dshgd", "bsdhgs", "dsgfdsfdgsf", "sda", "sdchb", "AJdfg", "sdfjgh","data" , "sad", "dfax" };;
    String result;
    ArrayList<String> myArray;
    Button b;
    int s;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        l= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        try {
            File file = new File("/sdcard/report.csv");
            if(!file.exists())
            {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "file Dont Exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            l= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
            myArray= new ArrayList<String>();


            try {
                String row;
                while((row= myReader.readLine())!=null)
                {

                    result= Arrays.toString(row.split(",")).replace("[", "").replace("]", "");

                    myArray.add(result);
                    ArrayAdapter<String> a= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row,R.id.text,myArray);
                    l.setAdapter(a);

                    //String result=Arrays.toString(row).replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",");
                    //resultList.add(data);
                    //resultList.add(result);
                    //myStringArrayList.add(result);
                    //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_xml,R.id.name, data);
                    //l.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

                myReader.close();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s.toString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        l.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });






    rowdata= new ArrayList<MainActivity.Inforowdata>();
    for(int i=0;i<myArray.size();i++)
    {
        rowdata.add(new Inforowdata(false,i));
    }
    l.setAdapter(new MyAdapter());

    rowdatab= new ArrayList<MainActivity.Inforowdatab>();
    for(int i=0;i<myArray.size();i++)
    {
        rowdatab.add(new Inforowdatab(false,i));
    }
    l.setAdapter(new MyAdapter());

    rowdatac= new ArrayList<MainActivity.Inforowdatac>();
    for(int i=0;i<myArray.size();i++)
    {
        rowdatac.add(new Inforowdatac(false,i));
    }
    l.setAdapter(new MyAdapter())   


}

class Inforowdata{
    public boolean isclicked=false;
    public int index;
    /*public String fanId;
    public String strAmount;*/

    public Inforowdata(boolean isclicked,int index/*,String fanId,String strAmount*/)
    {
        this.index=index;
        this.isclicked=isclicked;
        /*this.fanId=fanId;
        this.strAmount=strAmount;*/
    }
}


class Inforowdatab{
    public boolean isclicked=false;
    public int index;

    public Inforowdatab(boolean isclicked,int index/*,String fanId,String strAmount*/) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.index=index;
        this.isclicked=isclicked;
    }
}



class Inforowdatac{
    public boolean isclicked=false;
    public int index;

    public Inforowdatac(boolean isclicked,int index/*,String fanId,String strAmount*/) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.index=index;
        this.isclicked=isclicked;
    }
}
```

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return myArray.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return myArray.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View row= null;
    row= View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row,null);
    TextView  tv= (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text);
    tv.setText(myArray.get(position));

    //datab= myArray.get(position);


    CheckBox cba= (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.a);
    CheckBox cbb= (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.b);
    final CheckBox cbc= (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.c);

    cba.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(rowdata.get(position).isclicked)
        {
            rowdata.get(position).isclicked=false;
        }
        else
            rowdata.get(position).isclicked=true;
    }}
    );

    if (rowdata.get(position).isclicked) {

        cba.setChecked(true);

    }
    else {
        cba.setChecked(false);
    }
```

cbb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(rowdatab.get(position).isclicked)
        {
            rowdatab.get(position).isclicked=false;
        }
        else
            rowdatab.get(position).isclicked=true;
    }}
    );

    if (rowdatab.get(position).isclicked) {

        cbb.setChecked(true);
    }
    else {
        cbb.setChecked(false);
    }
```

cbc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(rowdatac.get(position).isclicked)
        {
            rowdatac.get(position).isclicked=false;
        }
        else
            rowdatac.get(position).isclicked=true;
    }}
    );

    if (rowdatac.get(position).isclicked) {

        cbc.setChecked(true);
    }
    else {
        cbc.setChecked(false);
    }
    b= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to get your row value from OnItemClickListener of ListView you will get all data of selected row

Comment: i want to save data of all rows when i click on a button..so how to get data from each row

Comment: @Ish i am not selecting any row here, i am trying to get data of all rows, both text and value of checkboxes which are checked in each row..there are three checkboxes in each row !!

Comment: I think..when you click on the button you wanna retrieve the listview whose checkboxes were selected..?
is this your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

To get all data from the list,

You need to create global adapter as

```
MyAdapter mAdapter;
```

`onClick` event of button by following code to get all data

```
for(Inforowdata row : mAdapter){
              //All rows adata here....
           }
```

or

```
for(int pos=0;mAdapter.getItemCount()-1;pos++)
     mAdapter.getItem(pos)//All rows adata here....
```

Comment: @RiggsFolly but i am trying to save all data when i click on submit button, not by setOnItemClickListener..

Comment: I didn't answer the question I just tidied up some skruffy code layout. Talk to @Ish

Comment: @user2589011 I edited my answer, check it, If you don't want to declare your adapter public, then you can use lsitView method getItemAtPos(pos)

Comment: You setting adapter  l.setAdapter(new MyAdapter()); Three times in your activity in single listview,,,only last one will reflect first two does't affect code, explain these lines